# Summing up values inside an array of hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following array of hashes:

```
books = [
  {'author' => 'John Doe', 'month' => 'June', 'sales' => 500},
  {'author' => 'George Doe', 'month' => 'June', 'sales' => 600},
  {'author' => 'John Doe', 'month' => 'July', 'sales' => 700},
  {'author' => 'George Doe', 'month' => 'July', 'sales' => 800}
]
```

Out of this, how can I get an array, with the following:

```
[
  {'author' => 'John Doe', 'total_sales' => 1200},
  {'author' => 'George Doe', 'total_sales' => 1400}
]
```

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. Did you research this? Where? If it didn't help tell us why. What did you try? If you didn't try, why not? If you did, what did you do? We'd like to see your minimal attempt to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the form of [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged:

```
books.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g['author']=>g['sales']) { |_,o,n| o+n }
end.map { |k,v| { 'author'=>k, 'total_sales'=>v } } 
  #=> [{"author"=>"John Doe", "total_sales"=>1200},
  #    {"author"=>"George Doe", "total_sales"=>1400}]
```

See the doc for a description of the block variables `_`, `o` and `n`. (I used `_` for the common key, mainly to signal to the reader that it is not used in the block calculation, a common Ruby convention.)

Consider stopping after the hash has been constructed:

```
books.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g['author']=>g['sales']) { |_,o,n| o+n }
end
  #=> {"John Doe"=>1200, "George Doe"=>1400}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `each_with_object` with an appropriate default:

```
default = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = { 'author' => k, 'total_sales' => 0 } }
books.each_with_object(default) do |h, memo|
  memo[h['author']]['total_sales'] += h['sales']
end.values
```

Outputs:

```
[
  {"author"=>"John Doe", "total_sales"=>1200}, 
  {"author"=>"George Doe", "total_sales"=>1400}
]
```

Comment: Very nice use of a default hash.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Enumerable#group_by` to get an array of array. Then you can merge the hashes of each array using `Enumerable#reduce` and `Hash#merge`.

```rb
group_books = books.group_by { |h| h['author'] }.values
result = group_books.map do |ary|
  ary.reduce do |new_hash, h|
    new_hash.merge(h) { |k, v1, v2| k == 'sales' ? v1 + v2 : v1 }
  end
end
```

EDIT : I forgot to remove the key `month` with `Hash#delete`.

```
result.map { |h| h.delete('month') }
```

Comment: No need for "EDIT:". Just revise your answer silently, as you would if you were editing a draft of an article you were writing.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
sales = ->(hash) { hash['sales'] }
books.group_by { |book| book.slice('author') }
     .map { |result, books| result.merge('total_sales' => books.sum(&sales)) }
#=> [
#   {"author"=>"John Doe", "total_sales"=>1200},
#   {"author"=>"George Doe", "total_sales"=>1400}
# ]
```

The code mostly speaks for itself. I first [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) a [`slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-slice) of the hash. Then [`merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) the [`sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-sum) of the sales values from `books`.

I've extracted the `sum` block to a [lambda](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Procs) and saved that in the `sales` variable to not clutter the `map` block with nested blocks.